# Returned struct calls it's own destructor that destroys allocated object

Tags: c++, return, destructor

NewSocketException():

```
SocketException NewSocketException(string callstack,Socket* socket)
{
    SocketException se;
    se.callStack = callstack;
    se.message = GetLastWinsockErrorMessage(&se.code);
    if (socket != nullptr)
        se.socket = new Socket(*socket);
    return se;
}
```

`NewSocketException()` should make `SocketException` struct for me and return it. C++ calls `se.~SocketException()` (it deletes `se.socket`) when `return se;` is executed. I guess that's because `se` goes out of scope but it's returned also so I don't know exactly what is going on over here. When this line is done:

```
 SocketException se = NewSocketException("accept() in AcceptThread()",server);
```

`se` contains correct strings (by stepping into I noticed that strings are also being destroyed by ~basic_string() but they are still there when function returns) and correct (the same) pointer value but objet (se.socket) is still destroyed. Why destructor is being called ? Why my object is gone and strings are still there ?

Comment: *Why is the destructor being called?* Because the lifetime of the local object has ended. *Why are the objects still there?* Because [the hotel does not guarantee it will remove the stuff you left in the drawer immediately after you check out of your room](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6441218/50079).

Comment: Once you decrypt how the linked answer is related to your question, consider that by your own example you're violating the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: At some point you think that you know a lot and heard a lot and something like this happens and you realize that you barely scratched the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a local variable   `se`from function, and its scope ends when your code reach last brace of the function. So it will call the destroctor.

To resolve the issue define a variable before calling the function and pass it as argument to your function.

```
SocketException se;

void NewSocketException(string callstack,Socket* socket, SocketException &se)
{

    se.callStack = callstack;
    se.message = GetLastWinsockErrorMessage(&se.code);
    if (socket != nullptr)
        se.socket = new Socket(*socket);
 }
```

Comment: Yea, this makes sense. Reference but I can still avoid dangerous `new` operator.

Comment: @MaciejSzpakowski you can handle externally  it after you process `SocketException `